# Variables in HTML

Tags: forms, html, input

I need a help with variables in html. 
My application gets the SQL requests and send them to Oracle and returns to the users the requested data from database. Before to send the request the user has to choose the Start date and End date. The data are shown by ajax and I have many of this SQL in one "index.php". Imagine, one document with 10 SQL queries and  with Dates places as follow:

```
//Dates box
<div class="date_boxes">
<div class="control-group">
<strong>Start Date:</strong> 
<input type="text" value="choose the start date" id="startDate" name="startDate"  class="startDate"
onfocus="if (this.value == 'choose the start date') {this.value = '';}" 
onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'choose the start date'; }"/>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<strong>End Date:</strong> 
<input type="text" value="choose the end date" id="endDate" name="endDate" class="endDate"
onfocus="if (this.value == 'choose the end date') {this.value = '';}" 
onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'choose the end date'; }"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Each of them are the same, but with different ID. How can I put the variable to this code. Can I use php variables or this should be in JavaScript? Do you have any examples?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Note down that there is no variable concept in html,
You can do this by using php, not by javascript, because javascript is client side scriprting language and php is server side scripting language. So, you need a server scripting language to access database.

you should have a query such like this one

```
select * from table_name
where date > start_date and date < end_date;
```

Comment: Probably, I explained the problem not so clear. I need to do something like this, but I am not sure that with ID I can do that.

<input id=<?php $variable;>>
or 
<var variable_1 = startDate;
var variable_2 = endDate>

Or I need to write the function, which will call the data box with required id everytime when in SQL we will need to chose the data.

But I am sure, that I do not need to work with sql. 

If you someone has any examples how can I make the injection.

Comment: you can not use this one <var variable_1 = startDate; var variable_2 = endDate>

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in html file

```
<form name=f1 action='index.php' method=post>
<input type=text name=start_date size=20><br/>
<input type=text name=end_date size=20><br/>
<input type=submit value=submit>
<input type=reset value=Reset>
</form>
```

and in index.php write this code after writing connection to the server and selecting database

```
$start_date=$_POST['start_date'];
$end_date=$_POST['end_date'];
$query='select * from table_name
where date > '.$start_date.' and date <'.$end_date;

$result=mysql_query($query,$connection) or die mysql_error($connection);
```

then after use result variable according to your need